# Using gspread to extract sheet ID

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

Can't seem to find any answer to this, but are there any functions/methods which can get a worksheet ID?

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

        ....code to authorize credentials goes here....

        sheet = client.open(str(self.googleSheetFile)).worksheet(str(self.worksheet))

        client.import_csv('abcdefg1234567abcdefg1234567', contents)
```

but I don't want to hardcode the `abcdefg1234567abcdefg1234567`. Is there anything I can do, like `sheet.id()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- In order to use `import_csv`, you want to retrieve the Spreadsheet ID from `sheet = client.open(str(self.googleSheetFile)).worksheet(str(self.worksheet))`.
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.

In this case, you can retrieve the Spreadsheet ID from `client.open(str(self.googleSheetFile))`. So please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
sheet = client.open(str(self.googleSheetFile)).worksheet(str(self.worksheet))

client.import_csv('abcdefg1234567abcdefg1234567', contents)
```

#### To:

```
spreadsheet = client.open(str(self.googleSheetFile))
sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(str(self.worksheet))
client.import_csv(spreadsheet.id, contents)
```

#### Note:

- When I saw the document of gspread, it says as follows. So please be careful this.

  > This method removes all other worksheets and then entirely replaces the contents of the first worksheet.
- This modified script supposes that you have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API with gspread.

#### Reference:

- [import_csv(file_id, data)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=import_csv#gspread.Client.import_csv)

Comment: @Sultan of Swing Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.